# Aws Ecs Taskdefinition - Setup Docker Logrotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, devops, amazon-ecs

i want to create a task definition in aws to run my docker container in Aws Ecs. I want to pass options like

```
--log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=5
```

Anyone an idea how I can pass this commands through the task definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_storage) & [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_LogConfiguration.html) you can find the way to define these in the ECS task definition.

For example, you can define the key-values that you want, in the `options` object, like:

```
"logConfiguration": {
    ...
    "options": {
        "max-size": "10m",
        "max-file": "5",
    },
    ...
}
```